# JSP mysql and utf8

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, utf-8

I am trying to store data encoded in greek through my JSP page in a mysql database using an insert statement. I have set the mysql arrays collation to utf 8. I have already used the

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

statements and I have made the proper  modification to the server.xml of the tomcat server ...

Any other ideas???

Comment: Have you checked if the UTF-8 header property is received by the browser after you access the JSP? Something like `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: yes i have added the charset=utf-8 to my jsps

Comment: Reading your question again I do not understand what problem you are trying to solve. Please provide more steps to reproduce the problem and please declare how you know that characters are not UTF-8 AND not in Greek by the time you receive it in your system.

Comment: The problem is that although i have specified my JSP pages to be utf 8 encoded as well as the mysql tables, data stored from jsp forms to mysql appears as ???????? ?????? etc... even within the database

Answer (score 1):

set collation  `greek_general_ci`.

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE greek_general_ci;
```

**EDIT:**

In MySQL Workbench right click on table->Alter Table--> change Collation to greek_general_ci or greekbin

Comment: you have problem with encoding? when run a select in your db what result have you?

Comment: check if the collation change in your table.
 I have the same problem  and it works for me.

Comment: you have problem with encoding? can you describe the problem?
also post your code plz

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to read UTF-8 characters (data is inputed as UTF-8 as you stated) using the Greek charset or other encoding that do not have equivalent Unicode chars.

Question marks or equivalent are shown when the byte (or bytes) do not have any association with the encoding you are using. You are parsing bytes that your client does not understand as valid, there is no representation.

I recommend you to read [this very helpful article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) before you continue:

> For example, you could encode the Unicode string for Hello (U+0048
>   U+0065 U+006C U+006C U+006F) in ASCII, or the old OEM Greek Encoding,
>   or the Hebrew ANSI Encoding, or any of several hundred encodings that
>   have been invented so far, with one catch: some of the letters might
>   not show up! If there's no equivalent for the Unicode code point
>   you're trying to represent in the encoding you're trying to represent
>   it in, you usually get a little question mark: ? or, if you're really
>   good, a box. Which did you get? -> �

Also the problem is not in your database or table/column encoding. It would only apply if you were using stored procedures for example.

***Make sure*** your browser is operating in UTF-8 when inputing or showing information. Using Chrome you can go to Tools > Encoding, the Unicode UTF-8 should be set after you open your JSP in the browser. You can also debug the request/response in the Network tab. If you are inputing data as UTF-8, read it as UTF-8.

You dont need to change Tomcat config or use the HttpFilter to set encoding if you are doing it in the JSP. I was able to simulate your problem using only the following config:

*ISO-8859-7 is a Greek Encoding that I used to read unicode and simulate your problem*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-7" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-7"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-7">
</head>
</html>
```

If this does not help I ask you to post complete details and source code of your application.